# The docker container loses port forwarding after running benchmarks

Tags: docker, ubuntu

The docker container loses port forwarding after running benchmarks, it can be reproduced 100%.

Environment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, docker 19.03.11, [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk) 4.1.0.

```sh
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name my-nginx nginx:1.18

netstat -ntulp | grep 8080
# tcp6    0     0    :::8080     :::*     LISTEN  6237/docker-proxy

# at the beginning of this benchmark, my-nginx can still be accessed through localhost:8080
wrk -t12 -c1000 -d30s http://localhost:8080

netstat -ntulp | grep 8080
# empty

wrk -t12 -c1000 -d30s http://localhost:8080
# unable to connect to localhost:8080 Connection refused

# get my-nginx's ip
docker inspect my-nginx
# my-nginx can be accessed through container_ip:80
wrk -t12 -c1000 -d30s http://172.17.0.2:80
```

Is this a bug or expected behavior of docker?

UPDATE: This seems to be a long-standing problem https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8817